# Adding new field on Process Instance object

Tags: object

How can I add/create a new filed on 'Process Instance' object? can we add it or not?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot add custom fields to approval processes/instances/steps/etc.

Comment: :- Is there any separate name for this type of objects(like process instance object) which won't be visible on UI but only on backend

Comment: @Sivananda2320 What do you want this for? You can create an object only visible to code if you want to.

Comment: Came to see this...Was wondering how I can create a Case Approval history report with Case, Account details without a Dev. :/

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, you can add new fields to Process Instances; even custom fields.

Setup > Approval Processes > Approval Process Name > Edit > Approval Page Layout